# Ошибка в SQL запросе в Room

Tags: android, android-room

Не смог отыскать понятной для себя документации по Query запросам в  Room. Вроде все относительно получилось, но остался последний запрос. Мне необходимо создать список, отбирая только те записи, где поле check ( тип boolean ) равно true.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Recept WHERE `check` == true")
LiveData<List<Recept>> getLike();
```

Как видно на скрине, у меня ошибка. Подскажите, как правильно построить запрос.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47730858/12191177, room превращает Boolean в INTEGER и его значения в 1 и 0. так что можно написать `check = 1`

Answer (score 1):

SQLite не имеет такого типа данных как `boolean`. Room мапит эти значения в колонки с `INTEGER` где `true = 1`, а `false = 0`

Этот код должен решить вашу проблему:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Recept WHERE check = 1")
LiveData<List<Recept>> getLike();
```

Имейте в виду, что это поведение не документировано. Тем не менее, он не должен меняться - по крайней мере, без какого-либо предупреждения. Т.к. тогда придется заниматься миграцией Базы Данных.